# ReactJS: TypeError: this.props.onGoogleSignIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a frustrating problem with a seemingly simple ReactJS app. 
When the user clicks "Sign on with Google", I want it to call a function defined in App.js.

Here's the function as defined in App.js (full App.js code [here](http://pastebin.com/eTBQsVCD)):

```
googleSignIn() {
  // Call Firebase
  let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var username = result.user.email;

    this.setState({
    user: {
        username
      }
    })
  })
```

}

Later in App.js, I pass the function as a prop to a child component:

```
<LoginBox 
     onGoogleSignIn={this.googleSignIn.bind(this)}
/>
```

And here's snipped from the LoginBox component (full LoginBox.js code [here](http://pastebin.com/mzNX8SZN)):

```
handleGoogleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onGoogleSignIn();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="middlePage">
            // bunch of HTML here...
            <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.handleGoogleSignIn.bind(this)} 
className='btn btn-block btn-social btn-google'>
<span className='fa fa-google'></span> Sign in with Google</a>
            // more HTML here...
    ) 
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onGoogleSignIn is not a function**

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It isn't enough code. Provide full `App.js` and `LoginBox.js` code to any service like pastebin.

Comment: Yes, made two components with you setup and works. Must be something else.

Comment: I edited my post and included links to the full App.js and LoginBox.js code in my question above. Thanks!